# angular can't parse JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, api, flask, get

I defined a very basic RESTful API on `FLASK`:

```
tasks=[
     {
        'id': 1,
        'title': u'Buy groceries',
        'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol', 
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': u'Learn Python',
        'description': u'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web', 
        'done': False
    }
]

@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'myTasks': tasks})
```

I'm trying to get the JSON  on ANGULARJS using the following simple code:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="studentController">
{{students[0].id}}
</div>
<script>
function studentController($scope,$http) {
    console.log('hi');
var url="http://172.56.4.30:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks";
 $http.jsonp(url).success( function(response) {
    $scope.students = response.data;
   console.log('hi2');
 });
}
</script>
```

But I'm keep getting this annoying error when I run the code on Chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

why??

Comment: Examine the response to `http://172.56.4.30:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks` in your Browsers debugging network panel - odds are it won't be valid JSON.

Comment: @thebluefox - you can examine it. For me it works fine.

Comment: escape your json and it works \' , then remember that the strings should be "" delimited

Comment: @InferOn I'm sorry, but how should I add the \'  ?

Comment: u'Buy groceries' can't be a valid json string, you have to escape it

Comment: @InferOn so should the JSON look like that: tasks=[
     {
        'id': 1,
        'title': \'Buy groceries',
        'description': \'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol', 
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': \'Learn Python',
        'description': \'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web', 
        'done': False
    }
]

Comment: Shan't be clicking a link like that I'm afraid @beniev - but given InferOn's reply it sounds like it indeed isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @InferOn so how should the JSON look like? If one of you will post it as an answer I will happily accept it..

Comment: Can you paste in the string response from your browser's network panel? The two example JSON strings you've tried to give us are both different?